# Google ads BigQuery data transfer using service accounts

Tags: google-bigquery, google-ads-api

i am trying to create Google ads bigquery data transfer service with service accounts.

i could not find the Google document which explain step by step to setup this transfer.

i can find nice document for setting up data transfer using user accounts.
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/google-ads-transfer

the only document i can see related to service account is
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/use-service-accounts#update_data_transfer_credentials
and it is not explain how to add this service account to Google ads.

Can someone help me to direct the right documentation page that explain in step by step for how to setup Bigquery data transfer service using service accounts.